# Filing one unique column by merging one data frame with several others

Tags: r

I have three data frames such as

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C","D","E"), nr = c(1,2,7,5,4))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), age = c(22, 26))
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "E"), age = c(31, 23))
```

`df1` contains all different persons (i.e. IDs) but does not provide information about the age, while `df2`and `df3` provide age for only some of the persons. I would like to create a column "age" in `df1` then fill it incrementally from the age column of `df2` then `df3`. I tried to do so using the `merge` function with `by = "ID"`, but the output is like

```
ID nr age.x age.y
A  1  NA    31
B  2  22    NA
C  7  26    NA
D  5  NA    NA
E  4  NA    23
```

while I would like to get this:

```
ID nr age
A  1  31
B  2  22
C  7  26
D  5  NA
E  4  23
```

Any idea?

Thanks for helping,
Val

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `rbind` second and third data frames first and then merge, i.e.

```
merge(df1, rbind(df2, df3), by = 'ID', all.x = TRUE)

#  ID nr age
#1  A  1  31
#2  B  2  22
#3  C  7  26
#4  D  5  NA
#5  E  4  23
```